# Problems with folder permissions using samba

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, windows-8, samba, file-sharing

I'm having issues with sharing a folder with Samba over my LAN. I created the fileshare by mounting one of my drives, then running
    gksudo nautilus
and sharing the folder using the built-in sharing function on 14.04 (this required samba to be downloaded and installed so I did that).

The issue is with one user on my home network. On my Windows 8 machine using the Samba user and password I set up with `smbpasswd -a <user>`.

I can log in to the machine through network discovery and access the shared drive fine with read and write commands ok. However, on my Win7 machine downstairs I am able to view the folder through network discovery, I don't have the right permissions to actually open the folder or edit anything in there. This is using another samba account I created with `smbpasswd -a <user>`

I've tried removing saved passwords for the server with the command `net use \\Server /delete`
although that hasn't done anything except prompt me for the password again once I access the drive in the network settings.

I have tried adding the new samba account to the smbusers (I think) group but with no changes.

I can dump my smb.conf if someone tells me how to.
Thanks.

Comment: Tale a look at the logfiles while trying from the win7 box and post the relevant portion in your question.

Comment: How do I access the logs? I've tried running '# smbd -l /home/james/Documents/samba/' and '# nmbd -l /home/james/Documents/samba/' but it seems the log files haven't been updated.

Comment: Logfiles are usually kept under `/var/log`...

Comment: Got it, here's the error
`[2014/10/29 20:11:43.026217,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4365(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/shared failed. Permission denied`

Comment: `Permission denied` means that the folder can't be accessed on a file level base. Just like on windows, you have permissions on the share and on the underlying FS...

Comment: For some reason I can't get an updated log file any more. I've tried making the location /var/log/samba but it's not updating the log file.

Comment: You must give your smb.conf for checking .. else check if you have something like this for your shared folder

 [shared_folder]
    path = /shared_folder
    browsable = yes
    available = yes
    read only = no
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 777
    directory mask = 777
    force create mode = 777
    force directory mode = 777

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Ubuntu. Make sure you have a space on BOTH sides of the '=' sign in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file. Samba is really picky.

Also when you change something in samba, restart it like this: `sudo restart smbd; sudo restart nmbd`

[Here's a link I tried too](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/samba-in-14-04-broken/1301).

To show you smb.conf file do this: `testparm -s`

You can send that output to a file, and open the file in nedit (requires X windows).

Use `smbstatus` to show all samba users.

Here's my script to get all samba and other related settings into a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# July 2014. Show system config for Samba.
yymmdd=`date +%F`
outfile="cfgsamba$yymmdd.txt"
myline="========================================="
[ -f "$outfile" ] && rm $outfile
date >> $outfile

echo $myline >> $outfile
echo "OS Version:" >> $outfile
echo " " >> $outfile
cat /etc/os-release >> $outfile

echo $myline >> $outfile
echo "Basic variables:" >> $outfile
echo " " >> $outfile
echo "TERM=$TERM" >> $outfile
echo "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" >> $outfile
echo "SHELL=$SHELL" >> $outfile
echo "BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION" >> $outfile
echo "Uname=`uname -a`" >> $outfile

echo $myline >> $outfile
echo "smbstatus:" >> $outfile
echo " " >> $outfile
#smbstatus >> $outfile 2>&1
stdbuf -oL smbstatus >> $outfile 2>&1

echo $myline >> $outfile
echo "sudo pdbedit -L:" >> $outfile
echo " " >> $outfile
sudo pdbedit -L >> $outfile

echo $myline >> $outfile
echo "testparm -s:" >> $outfile
echo " " >> $outfile
testparm -s >> $outfile

echo $myline >> $outfile
echo "smbclient -L ubuntucomp:" >> $outfile
echo " " >> $outfile
smbclient -L ubuntucomp >> $outfile

echo $myline >> $outfile
echo "net usershare info:" >> $outfile
echo " " >> $outfile
net usershare info >> $outfile

echo "See $outfile"
more $outfile
```

In the smb.conf [global] section you have to put in your `workgroup = WORKGROUP`. The default is literally 'WORKGROUP' all caps. Then restart samba.

Also in your [sambashare] section of smb.conf put in `read only = no`. Use the actual name for [sambashare]. Watch those spaces.